# Adding two complex numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I made the adding of two complex numbers in Haskell like this:

```
data Complex = C
{ realC :: Double
, imgC  :: Double
} deriving Show


addC :: Complex -> Complex -> Complex
addC (C a b) (C c d)= C (a+c) (b+d)
```

My question is: Can i make the above function (addC) point-free?

Answer (score 3):

Yup:

```
addC = ap (ap . (C .) . (. realC) . (+) . realC) ((. imgC) . (+) . imgC)
```

Obviously I do not recommend this. You can learn this yourself by asking lambdabot to point-free-ify things in the #haskell IRC channel, or download and use it yourself [from Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lambdabot). This is the command I ran to get the above definition:

```
?pl addC l r = C (realC l + realC r) (imgC l + imgC r)
```

However, when doing it by hand, it is often possible to make more readable results. For example:

```
addC = liftA2 (liftA2 C) ((+) `on` realC) ((+) `on` imgC)
```

Even with this somewhat decipherable version, I would still strongly prefer the code you wrote; your code is simple, it's blazingly obvious what it does, and that style makes it hard to get the code wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me what is "ap"?

Comment: @JoeDonald You can use [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle) to find [the documentation for `ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap). With the reader monad, `ap :: (e -> a -> b) -> (e -> a) -> (e -> b)`, which allows you to pass a single argument to two sub-functions. That is, `ap f g x` is `f x (g x)`, which passes `x` to both `f` and `g`. So when a given argument is duplicated on the RHS of an equation, `?pl` will often reply with a term that mentions `ap`.

Comment: Thanks for help, I was just curious.